# Node.js NPM config error - " Error: Cannot find module './config/mail' "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

Im following a book called "Building Node Applications with Mongo and Backbone". What im creating is a small social network site. Ive followed the steps through but am getting an error with npm config (I think)

when i run the app.js file it comes up with this error

```
>   Error: Cannot find module './config/mail'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

this is the relevant code its referring to.

```
// Import the data layer
var config = {
    mail: require('./config/mail')
};
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Well, does `./config/mail.js` exist in relation to file running it?

Comment: is it looking for npm_modules/config/mail.js ? If so its not there.

Comment: No, it's a relative path. If `app.js` is in directory `/home/` and you `require('./config/mail')`, it will look for `/home/config/mail.js` or `/home/config/mail/index.js`.

Comment: Ok so mail.js is nowhere to be seen so maybe its not installed correctly. Should it not be part of the "npm install config" command or do i need to find it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install module with npm as admin in console: sudo npm install